# Deleting a character array after using strcat causes a seg fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, strcat

In my code I am using system() to call a function that exists only on the raspberry pi's shell, specifically "raspistill"

When doing this, I use a char[] and strcat() as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  if(argc != 2) return -1;
  char command[] = "raspistill -o ";
  strcat(command, argv[1]);
  system(command);
  delete[] command;
  return 0;
}
```

I get a warning saying that the length to be deleted is 15, the initial length when initializing command, instead of the new length after the strcat function.

This problem goes away when I use a C++ string with append() instead. Why does this cause a seg fault and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Where are you allocating `name`

Comment: name is not defined anywhere. Why use C style strings anyway? Use std::string.

Comment: @rlbond I fixed my code, I had a few typos in there. I didn't mean to write name, I meant to write command

Comment: @Steve that was a typo, sorry. See my comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to invoke `strcat` on a char[] to which you assigned a constant string literal. This will fail. Also, there is no reason for you to delete[] the aforementioned `command`, as you are not dynamically allocating it on the free store (e.g. using new[], malloc, etc.)

*Edit: The following was relevant to a previous revision of the question*

You're missing the `new[]` to go with the `delete[]`. The code you just posted shouldn't even be compiling, as you do not define `name` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, that was a few typos. The correct code is posted

Comment: Writing  to command is legal, that's not the cause of the failure.

Comment: While writing to command is legal, you should familiarze yourself w/ what `strcat` does. It concatenates the right hand side argument to the left hand side argument. Since command is being assigned a constant string literal, this will overflow.

Comment: @ChristianKiewiet I see this now. How can I initialize a C string like that? In order to not overflow.

Nevermind. I got it by doing this:
    char * name = new char;
    strcpy(name, "raspistill -o ");
    strcat(name, argv[1]);

Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you want to be writing C-code then have a look at `malloc`, `free`, `realloc` and/or `strdup`. E.g.: `char* command = strdup("raspistill -o ");` will allocate a new array of bytes on the free style and put the pointer to the aforementioned into `command` - you could then reallocate / extend the buffer by using `realloc` and then `strcat` your other buffer. Then again, it might be more efficient to precalculate the required space and allocate it all at once! Have a look at `strlen` and/or the `sizeof` keyword in order to find out how to do that.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianKiewiet, I really appreciate the help, I am still learning. If you look at my last comment I figured out how to do it with new() and strcat().

Comment: @Bobdriving given your posted comment, you realzie `new char;` allocates space for **one** char, right? Thus the ensuing `strcpy` and `strcat` leap from the cliff of sanity into the chasm of *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really C++. If you replace the

```
delete[] command;
```

with

```
free(command);
```

then you will get a C program. It will still be a buggy program however - my point is that there is very little C++ in your program.

The problem would be solved if you did fully embrace C++. In modern C++, you don't use `[]` arrays for anything (except in certain very special cases). If you want a collection of characters, where you can add and remove characters at will, then just use a `string`.

```
#include <string>
using std::string; 

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  if(argc != 2) return -1;
  string command = "raspistill -o ";
  command.append(argv[1]);
  system(command.c_str()); // unfortunately, system() doesn't accept string
                           // directly, must convert to pointer with .c_str()
  return 0;
}
```

You don't need to `delete` in well written (modern) C++. In fact, it would be a serious bug to attempt to `delete command` (or `delete &command`) here.

Don't use pointers (except `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` where you really want the 'action-at-a-distance' behaviour). Don't use `new`, and don't use `delete`.

Sorry if this doesn't answer your original question directly. But I feel that just jumping straight to C++ is the best approach in situations like this.

Comment: Minor,  `command.append(argv[1]);` is sufficient, and avoids introducing potential temporaries.

Comment: Agreed. I'll change it. And I was a little paranoid explictly putting `string(   )` around `argv[1]`. It might be a good habit, especially if you want to do `argv[1]+argv[2]`, which only works if you put `string` around both.

Comment: Sure. If you were just stacking up appends, then `command.append(argv[1]).append(" ").append(argv[2])` would work as well (and I'm somewhat taken aback by how few people utilize that feature of `std::string::append`).

Answer (score 0):

Buffer overrun I presume. `command` is not long enough. You're corrupting the stack. And worse you're using `delete` on memory that wasn't allocated on the heap.

Comment: The heap is the free store as I intended it. deleteing memory that wasn't newed if you prefer.

Comment: You're completely right, sorry for that comment. It's been a long day ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Sometimes the memory being in the free store even is not enough. Consider a member with automatic storage duration of a dynamically-allocated struct. You can't `delete` that. Please fix your answer to talk about storage duration!!! Your comment regarding `new` is good enough.